Question on the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus part 1 proof
During the proof of the FTC-part1 we define the accumulation function $F(x) = {\LARGE\int}_a^x f(t) dt$.
Applying the definition of the derivative we get that:
$ F'(x) = \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \dfrac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} = \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \dfrac{1}{h} {\LARGE\int}_x^{x+h} f(t) dt$
Then, for $h>0$, we start working in the interval $[x, x+h]$. We apply the Extreme Value Theorem and show that there exist $u,v \in [x, x+h]$ s.t. $f(u)$ is the absolute minimum and $f(v)$ is the absolute maximum in that interval.
Right next is where I get confused: the proof states that "we let $h \to 0$, thus $u \to x$ and $v \to x$".
Intuitively this makes good sense: as the interval $[x, x+h]$ gets smaller, this implies that $u$ and $v$ get closer to $x$.
However, I want to prove this rigorously, so can anyone verify that the following steps until the end of the proof are correct?
I define function $g(h)$ on $[x,x+h]$, such that $f(g(h))$ is the absolute minimum of function $f$ in the interval $[x, x+h]$. In some sense this function $g(h)$ is the $argmin(f)$ in the interval $[x,x+h]$.
Thus I get that:
$x \le g(h) \le x+h$ and it also holds that $\lim_\limits{h \to 0} x = x = \lim_\limits{h \to 0} (x+h)$
Applying the Squeeze theorem on the inequality I get that $\lim_\limits{h \to 0} g(h) = x$ as well
Repeating the process, I define function $p(h)$ on $[x,x+h]$, such that $f(p(h))$ is the absolute maximum of function $f$ in the interval $[x, x+h]$. In some sense this function $p(h)$ is the $argmax(f)$ in the interval $[x,x+h]$.
Thus I get that:
$x \le p(h) \le x+h$ and it holds that $\lim_\limits{h \to 0} x = x = \lim_\limits{h \to 0} (x+h)$
Applying the Squeeze theorem I get that $\lim_\limits{h \to 0} p(h) = x$ as well
Then I proceed with the final part of the FTC-part1 proof, with $t \in [x, x+h]$:
$f(g(h)) \le f(t) \le f(p(h)) \Rightarrow f(g(h))*h \le {\LARGE\int}_x^{x+h} f(t) dt \le f(p(h))*h \Rightarrow f(g(h)) \le \dfrac{1}{h} {\LARGE\int}_x^{x+h} f(t) dt \le f(p(h)) $
It holds that $\lim_\limits{h \to 0} f(p(h)) = f(\lim_\limits{h \to 0} p(h)) = f(x)$, by the rule of limit composition, since $f$ is continuous on $x$ and $\lim_\limits{h \to 0} p(h) = x$.
Likewise it holds that $\lim_\limits{h \to 0} f(g(h)) = f(\lim_\limits{h \to 0} g(h)) = f(x)$
Thus applying the Squeeze theorem once again I get that:
$ \lim_\limits{h \to 0} {\LARGE\int}_x^{x+h} f(t) = f(x) $
Are the above argmin/argmax steps necessary, or am I overcomplicating the proof?

Argmin and max is too much effort. Do you know the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits?

Sure, should I attempt to prove this part in that way? Where should I focus?

See here.
